# Finding the stationary distribution of a markov chain using the eigenvectors of the transition matrix

Tags: julia, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have been trying to find the stationary distribution `pi` for a transition matrix `P`
My example 5x5 Matrix P results in an eigenvector I get by doing the following:
Example P matrix:

```
0.5 0.2 0.3
0.6 0.2 0.2
0.1 0.8 0.1
```

```
eigenvalue, eigenvector = eigen(P)
```

I get a 5x1 Vector for the eigen value with the last element being eigenvalue of 1. I believe that `pi` should be some multiple of the eigenvector associated with that eigenvalue of 1. However, it seems like the eigenvectors I have are not a proportion of my `pi`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I have found that I should be doing eigen(P'). This at least gives me the correct eigenvectors, however how do I find the right multiple of the eigenvector to find `pi` without knowing in advance what `pi` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far the post is correct. The way to find the proportion, or scale, is to use the fact that the sum of the stationary distribution `pi` is always 1.

```
scale = 1/sum(eigenvector) # for the relevant eigenvector not the whole matrix
pi = eigenvector * scale
```